# Different types of reflection/TDR casic

Tags: reflection, tdr

I am trying to understand the theory of operation of a time domain reflectometer (TDR).

TDR is a time domain instrument with measurement the impedance versus the distance. If with a VNA one can measure s-parameters, then with TDR one measures impedance.

Why would TDR be called S-parameters measurement method?

Ok, if I know the impedances, then I can create matrix U= Z I, where Z and I are matrices. But How I can use TDR for S-parameter measurement?

I have found the some slides ([enter link description here](http://home.deib.polimi.it/svelto/didattica/materiale_didattico/materiale%20didattico_MRF/MRF%20Time%20domain%20reflectometry.pdf))

pictures from this pdf:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Q: What do they mean?
```

Those graphs are voltages at source terminal vs time.

The x-axis has two inflections, `t=0` and `t when wave reach the source again`. The input is always `Ei` and the second value you see is the voltage at input terminal after reflecting.

---

```
Q: How to get these?
```

Deriving `Zl=f(Eo,Ei)*Zo` using reflection coefficient formula,

$$Γ=\frac{\ Z_L-Z_o}{\ Z_L+Z_o}$$

rearranging

$$Z_L=\frac{-(Γ+1)Z_o}{(Γ-1)}$$

and using

$$Γ=\frac{E_o}{E_i}$$

we have

> $$Z_L=\frac{E_o+E_i}{E_i-E_o}Z_o$$

---

You can use this formula by substituting `Ei=1` and `Eo=-1/3 , 1/3, 0, 1`.
For example `Eo=-1/3`,
$$Z_L=\frac{1}{2}Z_o$$

Comment: it makes sense. Actually I dont unerstand, for exp, the picture with Z goes to infinity, why the reflection and initial part are equal?